# VS2015: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, dictionary, visual-studio-2015

Hello Visual Studio Pros

I'm working on a group project and one of the collaborators committed something that worked on his machine, and everyone else's in our group. Except mine.

It seems that my visual studio cannot find the resource dictionary Skins/MainSkin.xaml, even though the path cleary is specified correctly.
I have tried to find a solution but have come up empty handed.
Any of you that might know a fix to this?

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhkFk.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: That file is not in a source control, by the looks of it. Compare source code with yours. Also, all the files seems to be edited.

Comment: Which file is not in source control?

Comment: MainSkin.xaml file has no icon near indicating something is wrong with it. Try restarting visual studio and chack whether that changes.

Comment: I've restartet visual studio a couple of times. Deleted everything and cloned from the repository that the others use with no errors, and i still get the same errors.

Comment: Undo all changes and then delete and reclone repo.

Comment: That is what i have been doing, and i still get the errors

Comment: Do you right click on solution and press undo changes?

Comment: I have deleted my entire solution and pulled the newest that is working for everyone else.

Comment: You do realize that source control tracks local changes and thus you do not get the same source. You need to UNDO your pending changes.

Comment: No i actually didn't realise that. I have tried to do it now, but it doesn't seem like it will actually let me UNDO my pending changes. It keeps popping up with my 204 pending items no matter how many times i tell it to undo.

Comment: You are using TFS or git like source control? Just Google how to delete cached items for your type of source control.

Comment: I have been trying to delete the cached files for git for a solid hour now, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Open SkinMain.xaml properties and check whether everything matches other files (i.e. MainViewModel.cs).

Comment: We have found out the error originates from me using windows 7, and he is using windows 10. Somehow my presentation framework aero2 doesn't contain the same things as his. So far the only way i have found to fix this is by removing his styling.